# how to get redirected to a page whose link is stored in a variable?

Tags: javascript, html

var f="http://www.google.com";
'f' is a variable there is a link stored in f.
Is there anyway to place a link which can redirect us to a link in variable f?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anyway to place a link which can redirect us to a link in
>   variable f?

Use `window.location` <sup>[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)</sup>:

```
var f="http://www.google.com";
window.location = f;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var f="http://www.google.com";

//redirect code<br>
location.href = f
```